# OleDbException - "Record is too large" while reading a csv

Tags: csv, oledb

I have a csv file, that has many columns.  I am trying to read in a few of the columns using and OleDbDataAdapter, that has worked fine on many large files, albeit with not as many columns.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(_tempFilePath) + ";  Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;';";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Format(selectCmd.Command, Path.GetFileName(_tempFilePath)));
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
```

The select CMD at run time is fairly simple:

```
SELECT 
    [timestampGMT0600] AS [MeasureTimeStamp], 
    Bladepitch10min AS [MeasureValue], 
    20 AS [MeasureId]  
FROM [{0}] WHERE ( NOT (Bladepitch10min) IS NULL) AND( NOT ([timestampGMT0600]) IS NULL)
```

The code I'm using also creates a SCHEMA.INI file, with the fields listed as "Text Width 250", which has always worked in the past.

Googling the error gives mostly MS Access results, mentioning a limit of 2000characters, which can be overcome by switching to Memo fields... but since I am not using Access, any ideas how I might get round this?

I'd rather not switch to a different toolset as it is embedded into a live system, and works well apart from this error on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of the values in your CSV file is wider than 250 characters.  Try replacing "Text Width 250" with just "Memo" in your SCHEMA.INI file (you should only have to do that for the column that has the wider values in it).

Comment: Non of the individual fields are.  I even replaced every field with a fldxxx number, and still the same problem.  I believe it is because all the fields concatenated have a length of over 6000 char.